# stopSelf in Android service doesn't give a chance for onLocationChanged to fire before exiting

Tags: android, android-service, locationmanager

I have setup a service that basically runs every 15 mintues and does a requestLocationUpdates on the GPS provider. I have the listener setup in the service.

Now when the method onStartCommand comes to an end I do a stopSelf as I wish the service to terminate as I know in another 15 minutes it will launch again using the AlarmManager.

But the service quits before the listen event arrives with the location information.

If I comment out the stopSelf that the location is received.

How do I get the service to wait until the location is received. I thought about putting the stopSelf in the event of the onLocationChanged but it may not always fire.

The other way I though of was implementing a thread sleep, but this feels like a code smell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get just one location use [LocationManager.requestSingleUpdate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestSingleUpdate%28java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) and call service.stopSelf() in onLocationChanged().  If you are concerned about the GPS searching for a fix indefinitely (perhaps the user is in a cave), then setup a timer and stop the service when it exceeds your specific period of time.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But if i do a requestSingleUpdate its guaranteed that the event will fire? on my RequestLocationUpdates the event didn't fire until i sent GPS co-ords with the emulator. You mention implementing a timer, do you have an example. thanks once again

Comment: requestSingleUpdate() works the same as requestLocationUpdates(), except that it only requests one update. On a real device, these methods will start immediately and will only not-return a location if Android cannot receive information enough GPS satellites ... Seems you answered your questions as I was typing. Glad I could help.